# Border left always fill the empty space from container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code works ok if the amount of items `li` I have is longer than the height of the div container. However, if I only have one item, the border does not fill the empty space.

The following image illustrates the problem
[image]

As you can see I'm using a plugin to work with the scrollbar, called perfectScroll.

My code is pretty simple and you can see the issue in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9vz3vevy/).

```
<!-- This div has a 200px height fixed -->
<div class="col-md-5">
   <ul>
      <li>Text 1</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have a div `col-md-5` with margins (top and bottom)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/jjvm6ksf/)

make the ul height as its parent div

```
ul
 {
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #44A4E3;
  padding-left: 15px;
  min-height:100%; //ADD THIS
 }
```

Comment: If I do that, the first `border-left` of `ul` will stop expanding beyond the 200px.

Comment: my mistake, I copied the wrong code, min-height does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try this one then:

```
ul
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #44A4E3;
    padding-left: 15px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```